# How many Crew Dragon spacecraft are SpaceX planning to operate?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, dragon-v2

NASA has bought [six Crew Dragon flights](https://www.govconwire.com/2017/01/boeing-spacex-secure-additional-crewed-missions-under-nasas-commercial-space-transport-program/) and there is at least one [private flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Axiom_Space-1) booked for next year.  There are currently [two flight-capable Crew Dragon spacecraft](https://www.elonx.net/list-of-dragon-capsules/#dragon2).  Is SpaceX currently building more capsules and if so, how many?

Comment: Technically speaking, two should be enough for NASA's contracts. Building more is essentially risk management.

Comment: @JörgWMittag  Yes, and since SpaceX decided not to get Falcon Heavy certified for crewed flight the #dearMoon project has been moved to Starship.  However, I doubt Starship will be ready to carry people for some years, Musk himself has said that he expects "hundreds of missions with satellites before we put people on board", and his timeline estimates have always been very optimistic.

Comment: That's the beauty of not throwing rockets in the trash every time, and have a common design across crew and cargo: you accumulate heritage data *and* get paid for your "test flights".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Three cargo and five crew vehicles.

Gwynne Shotwell [answered this](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-reusable-dragon-spacecraft-fleet-details/)

> Specifically, Shotwell revealed that SpaceX intends to build three reusable Cargo Dragon 2 capsules, one of which is already completed and in Florida preparing for its December 2nd CRS-21 launch debut. On the crew side of things, SpaceX will build “three more” Crew Dragon capsules on top of the flight-proven Demo-2 and currently orbital Crew-1 capsules. It’s unclear if this means that the new Crew Dragon capsule flown on SpaceX’s January 2020 In-Flight Abort (IFA) test will be refurbished for additional flights.

> Excluding IFA Crew Dragon capsule C205, SpaceX thus intends to operate a fleet of at least three Cargo Dragon 2 and five Crew Dragon capsules, representing eight reusable spacecraft each capable of at least five orbital missions.